# Storing key-value pairs in a database column

Tags: database, dictionary, scalability, key-value

In my codebase I recently came across a design decision made by the team where key-value pairs are stored in a formatted manner within a database(Relational-mysql) column. There is a universal set of metadata and a subset of this metadata might be present for a particular record. For a given record, its metdata subset and its values are stored in a column in a formatted manner as follows:

```
Key1:Value1\n\nKey2:Value2\n\nKey3:Value3\n\n.....
```

To get the metadata for a given record-id would then boil down to just running a simple select and then parsing the result to populate a dictionary in memory.

The rationale for doing this was cited as follows:

> 1. Better performance than maintaining a denromalized table consisting of the columns recordId/Key/Value.
> 2. Scalability
> 3. To be conservative on space on the database server.

I can see the logic of storing these parings in the database column but something tells me this might cause problems in the longer run and may not be the panacea to our "scalability" woes.

Can somebody give some feedback on what might be wrong with this approach and what are some of the best practices on storage and retrieval of information like this on systems under heavy load.

Thanks

Comment: If you are doing a lot of keyvalue work, then a relational database is the wrong tool. Why not use a nosql database instead?

Comment: Well..the bulk of the system is transactional in nature, it makes little sense to introduce a NoSql database(with it bells and whistles) to tackle this one aspect of the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously it depends on the particular case, but this sort of 1NF violation is generally a bad approach. One significant problem is that you can't ever query on the metadata. (E.g., "SELECT WHERE key2 = 'value3'") Another is that you can't ever update a single key/value without parsing, adjusting, un-parsing, and rewriting the whole large set. To address the claims individually:

1. Has this claim actually been tested against your data? If you only ever need one key/value from the record, you currently have to pay the database overhead to read the whole set, the network overhead to transport it to the client, and the cpu overhead to parse out the one piece you need. Doing that job inherently is precisely what the database was designed for, so you're essentially disabling the component that excels at that sort of work and poorly emulating it with unnecessary client-side programming.
2. How do they figure that? Storing all key/value pairs in a single field will degrade as the number of pairs increases.
3. Almost certainly irrelevant. Disk space is cheaper than bad design.

P.S. What happens if you have a value with two newlines in it?

Comment: These are some excellent points. I also somewhat am partial towards Kolinks response regarding memcaching these values but that approach also needs to be evaluated.

Comment: Also note, the total size of your key/value set is going to be limited by the maximum size of a database field. That may not be an issue for your particular usage today, but it's not exactly what I'd call scalable. And, it's not like empty database fields actually take up space. And, if disk space is such an important issue, then why isn't the existing data being compressed? I.e., I think the explanations you've received are pretty presumptuous. Kudos for challenging them, it's a good catch.

Answer (score 2):

The big question is do they make sense in isolation / how often do you need to select individual pairs.

If it's mainly a property bag stored as name = value, and the pairs are related, then storing in one lump saves space and time.

If you wanted to easily access individual pairs quickly, then table with name and value columns makes sense, as long as they have unique names of course. That will use up more space, and if you need to access more than one in a hit, you lose some of the advantage.

There's no right or wrong to this one. There might be a best, but that could easily change. We use both approaches on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how often they are neede, key/value pairs can be better off stored in something like Memcache, so they can be accessed and updated by anyone virutally instantaneously.

For something not quite so critical, a simple key/value database table would work quite well, especially with the right engine backing it (eg. one better suited to reading fast than writing).

If it's more of an archive, then the format you have there could work well in a data file on the server rather than a database.

It all depends on what it's being used for, really.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an approach to making your relational database effectively into a [NoSQL database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL). I have used this technique before in systems where we were trying to squeak every bit of performance out the system, and it worked very well.  In one case the information was actually used in a call to a REST API and needed to be passed in a query string, so the information was stored as a query string (ex: "var1=val1&var2=val2") so the whole string could be passed as is to the API as is.  Parsing this format was very easy.  But your question is what are the issues of using this method of storing data.  I think the issues are the same ones that are solved by [normalizing your database as proposed by E.F. Codd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  But the reality is that databases are often de-normalized to achieve desired performance results and the NoSQL approach is gaining ground because of the large amounts of data that needs to be processed in today's systems.